# AngularJS: Store localized user input data in translation json files or database

Tags: angularjs, database, architecture, localization

I have an architecture issue related to localization. My concern is what is the best approach to store and manage localized **user data**. Let me explain:
I have an AngularJS webapp with a mysql database. For text translations we are using angular-translate with files. For labels, static text, etc is working great.

In the other hand, the user can create items (i.e. houses for rent) and fill a title and description for it. He also is able to edit that information. This information is gathered by a form and stored in DB at the moment.

We would like to provide translations for these user input data and with this scenario in mind, I see two approaches:

1. User stores data in his language in DB. We store the translations in DB (translations tables...) and provides translations from there.
2. User stores data in his language in DB. We store the translations in locale.json files and create an key in database to get those translations (angular-translate).

In both scenarios we need to translate whether the user creates or updates a title or description. But it looks like if you store it in database, at least you already have one default translation. If you store it in a json file, you are keeping the default translation data in two places.

From the maintainance point of view, to use the translation files looks a little more complex at first sight. Also, take into account each time a user input text is added or updated a deployment needs to be done.

However, from the performance point of view, probably the translation files is a better approach. Probably you are saving at least one query to the DB when the user change the language.

From the architectural point of view, I would say the user data should be stored in database.

What do you think?

Comment: Keeping data in 2 places is always a risk, since you can reach inconsistent states if the two get out of sync. A single source of truth can prevent bugs on the long run.

The performance impact negligible IMO.
If you do see performance issue at some point, you can optimize it in many ways later.

Comment: So your conclusion? To store it only in DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always store the user input.

Store the translation in DB only if you **ALWAYS** needs it.
If you rarely needs to do it offer a Transalation button for the user.

Do what's cheaper. If you got only one in a thousand inputs in another language and it's rarely visited there's no sense in wasting precious DB space, let it be done on the fly by demand.

Also how do you know it needs to be translated? Some people are billingual and there are cases where a abroad tourist is (strugling to) using a device set in another language.

Obs:.
Do You knows automatic translations are crap don't you? So how are you translating?

Comment: Translations are done by UX but also for SEO purposes. We will not translate user reviews, but product item descriptions. We are in a high competitive market, so SEO it´s really important. If a page is in english I think it´s nice to have a product description in english. Unfortunately, we will translate everything manually to avoid that crap translations :(.

Comment: @Rober In your scenario is mandatory to have each description persisted at the DB. Hope management dont forgot to budge that translation that can cost a small fortune

Comment: Thanks! As a graphic example, have a look at an Airbnb page: https://www.airbnb.es/s/Madrid/homes?place_id=ChIJgTwKgJcpQg0RaSKMYcHeNsQ&refinements%5B%5D=homes&allow_override%5B%5D=&s_tag=6WZCchAb the title of each list is created by the user. If you change the language, you can see the titles are translated. What do you think?

Comment: @Rober For pure coincidence AirBnb was exactly the example I had in mind. Sure you do need that Idiom and Currency combos. Translating titles are a lot easier than translating a paragraph but you still needs some professional translators. You don't want to lose a deal in that competitve market because somene tranlated Loft to Flat. For the "Immutable text" (buttons, menus, etc) you can create domains tables or use any localization tool for your technology.

Comment: For immutable text totally agree. As said in the problem description above, we are using angular-translate plugin which is using json locale files. But the point is: this cases such as titles... Do you buy to store them (the original and translation) in db then? (Of course in an appropiate multilanguage tables architecture)

Comment: @Rober As I said. That's mandatory or at least for start. If I was the guy responsible to maintain AirBnb I can study each access to validate it. How many spanish are accessing content in english for example. If a few and there are a lot of content so keeping starts to make less sense. But at first I can translate and persist.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: option 1. You may cache access to the translation tables or create materialised views (if your DBMS supports them) to denormalise your `Property` entity and have one readily-translated row per language.

Personally, I do not see the need for caching - how many times is the user going to change language, in production?